# giving loadstatic on heroku a path

Tags: django, heroku, static, path

When i try to load my staticfiles from my

```
/static/
```

folder to heroku with

```
heroku run python manage.py loadstatic
```

i get the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/hellodjango/static'
```

my setting file has this part

```
# Static asset configuration
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/
# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
('assets', "/home/ikke/hellodjango/static"),
)
```

Where do i go wrong? cause obvious the path it tries to load from is wrong. heroku uses django 1.6 and i used 1.5 before